# Changing ringer volume during ringing

Tags: android, settings, volume, android-audiomanager

I'd like to change the ringer volume during ringing. Code below sets it during ringing (it is changed in system settings) but it doesn't come to effect with actual ringing (only the next ring call will use new value). Can I force this changes to make them effect Immediately?

```
AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);    
audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, volume, AudioManager.FLAG_ALLOW_RINGER_MODES | AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research and tests I've found that volume change is possible only in very early stage of incomming call detection. It's vital not to do much operations inside the `onReceive()` method.

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver   {

private boolean isRinging = false;
private boolean isInProgress = false;
private Listener mListener = null;

// interface declaration
 public interface Listener {
        public void onPhoneStateChange(boolean state);
    }

// registration of listener
 public void registerListener (Listener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

        if(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state))  {
            // do something while ringing BUT NOT TOO MUCH!

            isRinging = true;

            if (context instanceof StateChecker)
                  ((StateChecker) context).serviceDestroy();
                Log.v("phone", "ringing");

        }


        else if(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE.equals(state))    {
            //do something when the call ends
            if (context instanceof StateChecker)
                  ((StateChecker) context).serviceStart();
            Log.v("phone", "idle");
            isRinging = false;
        }


        // sending notification to listener
        if(mListener != null)   {
            mListener.onPhoneStateChange(isRinging);

            Log.v("listener", "notified");


        }

}

}
```

and some code from service:

```
// listeners callbacks
public void onPhoneStateChange(boolean state) {

    if (state) {

        if (!callInProgress)    {

       // Do the main task here
        callInProgress = true;
        serviceDestroy();

        }

    } else {

        callInProgress = false;
        serviceStart();

    }
}
```

ServiceStart:

```
 // starting service
public void serviceStart()  {

    preferencesRead();

    //The intent to launch when the user clicks the expanded notification
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);



    if(settings.getBoolean("hide_noti_icon", false))    {
     Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
     .setContentTitle("Intelligent Ringer")
     .setContentText(getString(R.string.is_running))
     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.invisible)
     .setContentIntent(pendIntent)
     .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MIN)
     .build();

     startForeground(12345, noti); 


    } else  {

         Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
         .setContentTitle("Intelligent Ringer")
         .setContentText(getString(R.string.is_running))
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
         .setContentIntent(pendIntent)
         .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MIN)
         .build();

         startForeground(12345, noti); 
    }


    Log.v("service", "started");
    // registering listener for CallReceiver
    if(isCRRegistered)  {
        unregisterReceiver(mCallReceiver);
        isCRRegistered = false;
    }

    if(!isCRRegistered) {

     IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
     filter2.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
     CallReceiver mCallReceiver = new CallReceiver();
     this.mCallReceiver = mCallReceiver;
       registerReceiver(mCallReceiver, filter2);
       mCallReceiver.registerListener(this);
       isCRRegistered = true;
    }

    if(isScreenRegistered)  {
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        isScreenRegistered = false;
    }



    if(!isPositionRegistered && proximityOn)    {

        Position mPosition = new Position(this.getApplicationContext());
        mPosition.registerListener(this);
        mPosition.isInPocket();
        this.mPosition = mPosition;
        mPosition.register();

        isPositionRegistered = true;
}

    if(!isScreenRegistered) {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        ScreenReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        this.mReceiver = mReceiver;

        mReceiver.registerListener(this);

        isScreenRegistered = true;
    }


}
```

Servicedestroy()

```
// stopping service
public void serviceDestroy()    {


    if (this.mPosition != null) {
    this.mPosition.unregister();
    }

    Log.v("service", "Destroyed");

    if(isScreenRegistered)  {
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        isScreenRegistered = false;
    }

}
```

OnDestroy()

```
public void onDestroy () {
    serviceDestroy();


    if(isCRRegistered)  {

        unregisterReceiver(mCallReceiver);
        isCRRegistered = false;

        }
}
```

Comment: having same issue. What would be `early stage of incoming call detection` then ? Can you post some code plz ?

Comment: i have the same issue. can you help me with your solution.?

Comment: @Riser I've put some code in.It worked some time ago.

Comment: @soulreaver thanks for the help. can you put more code of your service. because i am confused regarding servicedestroy and servicestart method in it..

Comment: Thanks. stateChecker is your service name. right? and where you are calling registerListener method of CallReceiver .?

Comment: if you dont mind can you show whole code of service class.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138732/discussion-between-soulreaver-and-riser).