# PhoneStateListener and BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, phone-state-listener

I've created a BroadcastReceiver that listens to he phone states and act accordingly.

The problem here is that it doesn't seem to take the right values from my database, and from the beginning the toast in idle state shows twice, and after a second call shows four times etc...

I guess there is something wrong with my class but I can't figure out what...

Here is a code snippet :

```
public class PhoneListener extends BroadcastReceiver{

    private DBAdapter   db;
    private Cursor      data;
    private Cursor      options;
    private int     activer;
    private  int        mouvement;
    private int     verticalite;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephonyManager.listen(new CustomPhoneStateListener(context), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    }

    public void stopService(Context context){
        Intent alerte = new Intent(context, SensorOrientation.class);
        alerte.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.stopService(alerte);
    }

    public void startService(Context context){
        Intent alerte = new Intent(context, SensorOrientation.class);
        alerte.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startService(alerte);
    }

    public void startnotif(Context context){
        Intent intent   =   new Intent(context, SecuriteHauteReboot.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startService(intent);   
    }

    public class CustomPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

        //private static final String TAG = "PhoneStateChanged";
        Context context; //Context to make Toast if required 
        public CustomPhoneStateListener(Context context) {
            super();
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                db          =   new DBAdapter(context);
                data        =   db.selectWidget();
                options     =   db.selectVerticalite();
                activer     =   data.getInt(data.getColumnIndex("activer"));
                mouvement   =   options.getInt(options.getColumnIndex("activer_alarme_mouvement"));
                verticalite =   options.getInt(options.getColumnIndex("activer_alarme_verticalite"));
                data.close();
                options.close();
                //when Idle i.e no call
                Toast.makeText(context,
                        String.format(" "+mouvement+" "+activer),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(activer == 1){
                    if(mouvement == 1 || verticalite == 1){
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                                String.format("and I'm here...."),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startService(context);
                        startnotif(context);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                //when Off hook i.e in call
                //Make intent and start your service here
                if (activer == 1){
                    if(mouvement == 1 || verticalite == 1){
                        stopService(context);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                //when Ringing
                if (activer == 1){
                    if(mouvement == 1 || verticalite == 1){
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                                String.format("and I'm here...."),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        stopService(context);
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be doing to much inside the `onCallStateChanged` (database I/O operations). I've had similar issue with the `BroadcastReceiver` here: [Changing ringer volume during ringing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14429133/changing-ringer-volume-during-ringing/14489509#14489509) . For testing try to operate on static fields (instead of LiteSQL) inside `BroadcastReceiver` and check if it helps.

Comment: Thanks soulreaver! That was exactly the problem. I don't like to use too many static values so I simply created services and it works like a charm! Problem solved :)