# Why broadcast receiver for incoming calls does not work on lollipop when phone is in sleep mode

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, incoming-call

My goal is to always detect incoming calls, even if the phone is in sleep mode. However, I encountered some strange behaviour on lollipop.

THE PROBLEM:

When the phone is in stand by mode (isn't used for >10 minutes) broadcast receiver's onReceive() method doesn't get called.

This works perfectly on Kitkat, Marshmallow and Nougat. Maybe someone had the same problem?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />

<receiver android:name=".PhoneCallReceiver"
              android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Receiver:

```
public class PhoneCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
        String nr = Utils.fixNumber(intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER"));
        prefs.edit().putString("LastActiveNr", nr).apply();
    } else {
        String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

        int state = 0;

        if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE.equals(stateStr)) {

            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
            prefs.edit().putInt("state", state).apply();

        } else if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK.equals(stateStr)) {

            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
            prefs.edit().putInt("state", state).apply();

        } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
            prefs.edit().putInt("state", state).apply();
            String nr = Utils.fixNumber(intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER));
            prefs.edit().putString("LastActiveNr", nr).apply();
        }
        onCallStateChanged(context);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing to much inside your `onReceive()` method. I would try to move `prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);` outside the `onReceive()`. Of course this all should work inside [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html). This could help: [Changing ringer volume during ringing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14429133/changing-ringer-volume-during-ringing)

Comment: This is a question for another topic and I'm not sure what you're asking for. Maybe open another topic with your code and I'll try to help you. In general you need to register a `Listener` inside `BroadcastReceiver` and then you can call it `mListener.onPhoneStateChange(isRinging);`

Comment: I figured that out, i had to register mListener with an instance of that service which inherits interface

Comment: Still does not work all the time, even if onReceive() has as little code as possible

Comment: But i would have to use WakeLock all the time. Wouldn't it drain a lot of phone battery?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I just checked that in my code I used `Foreground Service`. It should be more battery friendly than `WakeLock` https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground

Comment: Are you detecting incoming calls through foreground service? Could you share how you do it? It would be very helpful

Comment: I can't give you all the code but here are some of it: https://pastebin.com/200zXJzM and https://pastebin.com/L02F8GT2

Comment: Do you have foreground service notification all the time? Do you get rid of it?

Comment: Yes, the notofication is persistent. Now in android 6.0 and newer user can turn off the notofication.